# How to Print QRCode Details?

Tags: fastapi

How do I print out QR code details with **FASTAPI**?

```
@app.post("/scan_qr")
async def scan_qr(image: UploadFile = File(...)):

try:
    # Read the uploaded image
    image_bytes = await image.read()
    qr_image = Image.open(image_bytes)

    # Scan the QR code
    qr_codes = pyzbar.decode(qr_image)

    if qr_codes:
        qr_data = qr_codes[0].data.decode("utf-8")
        return {"qr_data": qr_data}
    else:
        return {"error": "No QR code found."}

except UnicodeDecodeError:
    return {"error": "Unable to decode the QR code data."}
```

Comment: What's the issue with your current code? What's the actual problem you're having?